# Remotely access ADB server located inside a Docker container

Tags: android, docker, ssh, android-emulator, ssh-tunnel

I have a **Docker container** on a **host A**, which exports a **SSH** service on **port** 5022. 
E.g. If I want to connect to the container, I typically do `ssh -p 5022 user@hostA`.

**In the Docker container, I have an ADB server** (Android Debug Bridge) which is running on port 5037 (that's the default port). For example, I can run `adb devices` in the container to list all the Android devices and emulators which are connected.

**I would like to do that, but remotely, from host B**. So, from host B, I would like `adb devices` to be redirected to the ADB in my remote docker container.

I have tried to setup a tunnel such as this:
`ssh -L 9999:127.0.0.1:5037 -N -T -p 5022 user@hostA` 
and then `adb -H 127.0.0.1 -P 9999 devices` but it does not work :( and says `error: protocol fault (no status)` and `channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused` by the tunnel.

Tunnel:

`bash
$ ssh -L 9999:127.0.0.1:5037 -N -T -p 5022 user@hostA
user@hostA's password: 
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`

ADB:

`bash
$ adb -H 127.0.0.1 -P 9999 devices
error: protocol fault (no status)`

**Edit 1:**

I also tried (unsuccessfully): `ssh -N -T -L 9999:172.17.0.11:5037 -p 5022 user@host` where 172.17.0.11 is the local IP address of the docker container on `host`. And then `adb -H 127.0.0.1 -P 9999 devices` still unhappy `error: protocol fault (no status)`.

The output of `docker ps` is:

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
cef3d4daf9bc        cryptax/android-re   "/usr/bin/supervisord"   23 hours ago        Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:5037->5037/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5554->5554/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5900->5900/tcp, 5555/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5022->22/tcp   androidre`

The output of `docker inspect androidre` contains:

```
"HostConfig": {
...
    "PortBindings": {
                "22/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5022"
                    }
                ],
                "5037/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5037"
                    }
                ],
                "5554/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5554"
                    }
                ],
                "5900/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5900"
                    }
                ]
            },
...
 "Config": {
            "Hostname": "cef3d4daf9bc",
...
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "22/tcp": {},
                "5037/tcp": {},
                "5554/tcp": {},
                "5555/tcp": {},
                "5900/tcp": {}
            },
...

"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "HairpinMode": false,
...
            "Ports": {
                "22/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5022"
                    }
                ],
                "5037/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5037"
                    }
                ],
                "5554/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5554"
                    }
                ],
                "5555/tcp": null,
                "5900/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5900"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
...
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.11",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.11",
...
                }
```

Comment: please add output of `docker ps` from hostA

Comment: @TarunLalwani output added :)

Comment: Try this `ssh -L 9999:127.0.0.1:5037 -N -T user@hostA` Without going to `5022` instead using the host port 22

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I was able to gain access by putting the container on the host network, but would prefer to expose 5037 without putting the entire container on the host network.

Comment: no, didn't get it to work.